# Is it possible to clear ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: java

Let's assume I have the following:

```
final ByteArrayOutputStream boas = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
final byte[] sample = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
boas.write(sample);
```

At this point the backing array `byte buf[]` within `boas` contains the 10 bytes above (and 22 padding bytes).

If I call reset on `boas` the `count` and `size` and all other factors indicate it's empty but internally `byte buf[]` remains unchanged and populated.

Is there anyway to truly clear this down without creating an entirely new `ByteArrayOutputStream`?

More generally, is there a reason why ByteArrayOutputStream behaves like this rather than emptying the `byte[]`?

Comment: Why? What do you care what's in an internal data structure? Why should it bother to traverse the byte array when as you say yourself 'all other factors' indicate it's empty? What would be the point?

Comment: I don't there would generally have been much demand for such a feature.  Resetting the `BAOS` simply means that a pointer will be reset to the start, and subsequent additions will overwrite the old data.

Comment: Yes. `boas=null;` and wait for (or force) GC.  The question is why you want to do this.

Comment: @EJP I could care quite about an internal data structure a lot if I had some legacy code where someone hadn't read the javadocs correctly and assumed reset() actually reset the byte[] buffer.

Comment: Whether or not the data is left in the memory is immaterial if after `reset()` it behaves as if it is empty.

Comment: @imrichardcole No you couldn't. There is no way you could observe it. You said so yourself.

Comment: @EJP I can observe it in the sense it's still holding onto the memory?

Comment: @imrichardcole And you can observe that how? And if you really had legacy code that relies on the way it works now, why exactly would you want to change its behaviour? This isn't making much sense.

Comment: @EJP the point I'm trying to make is that if someone has misinterpreted the above there is a good chance you can have a boas laying around that's hogging a large amount of memory.

Comment: @imrichardcole The point is that if this 'legacy code' relies on an incorrect interpretation of the specification, either it hasn't been working all these years or it doesn't matter.

Comment: @EJP you sound surprised by `incorrect interpretation of the specification` as if this never happens in software development!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103685/discussion-between-imrichardcole-and-ejp).

Comment: Answer to question "why anyone would want to do this" is "having the ability to immediately erase the contents of allocated memory, without having to wait for GC to be executed at some point in time, is a fundamental security feature."

Answer (score 15):

The Javadoc of `ByteArrayOutputStream.reset()` states

> Resets the `count` field of this byte array output stream
>   to zero, so that all currently accumulated output in the output stream
>   is discarded. The output stream can be used again, reusing the already
>   allocated buffer space.

Performance wise it makes sense to reuse an already allocated buffer.

If you want a different behaviour you can derive a class from `ByteArrayOutputStream` and override `reset()`. Both `buf[]` and `count` are protected members, so for instance you could clear `buf` if you want.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question.  I'm guessing the bit that's open for interpretation in the docs is "so that all currently accumulated output in the output stream is discarded"

Comment: @imrichardcole discarded must then be interpreted as: it will not appear in the byte array returned by `toByteArray()`.

Comment: "Performance wise it makes sense to reuse an already allocated buffer." - Doesn't this depend on the size of the objects being written to the buffer since the buffer space isn't reduced for smaller size objects? Risking a high memory usage even for smaller objects?

Answer (score 1):

`ByteArrayOutputStream` provides no method to empty the `byte[] buf`. Take a look at [the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.java#ByteArrayOutputStream). [`buf`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.java#ByteArrayOutputStream.0buf) can not directly be modified.

You could write a class the inherits from `ByteArrayOutputStream` and add a method to empty  `buf`.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot unless do what others say in comments on your question.
Check amortized analysis(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis).
I guess the cost of erasing internal buffer memory every time is bad for performance.

Answer (score -1):

If your problem is to cope with old legacy code without modifying it, I understand there is some subclass of `ByteArrayOutputStream` reading the protected `buf` and `count` variables.

Given that:

1. JRE authors should have *never* made variables protected (it violates the most basic principle of OO encapsulation).
2. Legacy code author should have interpreted correctly the `ByteArrayOutputStream` API.
3. Current programmers (you) should probably throw away all the legacy code and write it down from the scratch.

... Given all of these points, I said, I guess that any fast solution to fix the problem easily won't do much more harm.

For example: If -as I understand- you have to maintain some `LegacyOutputStream` class as subclass of `ByteArrayOutputStream`, could you write down your own subclass?

```
public class MyFixOutputStream extends LegacyOutputStream
{
    @Override
    public void reset()
    {
        // Do here with this.buf wathever blunders required by LegacyOutputStream.
    }
}
```

... and then, replace in the existing code any use of `LegacyOutputStream` by `MyFixOutputStream`?